# Django modelform and passing extra parameter

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to populate my modelform to include the IP address, however I'm not able to set the ip as I want, it simply returns "This field is required" for IP address.

#### models.py

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    ....
    ip = models.IPAddressField()
```

#### views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST, ip_addr=get_client_ip(request))
```

#### forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ip_addr = kwargs.pop('ip_addr', None)
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_ip(self):
        return self.ip_addr
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't actually set an initial value for the ip form field meaning it's empty. Try:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['ip'].initial = kwargs.pop('ip_addr', None)
```

[The `clean_ip` method is for validation upon](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) submission of the form and is only called after `form.is_valid()` is called. It should check that the value of the field is a valid ip

Comment: I get 'SignUpForm' object has no attribute 'fields'. I think this works for regular forms but not for modalforms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use `clean_ip` here. You are not cleaning it anyhow. Either use [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) in your view or override `save` method.